# Show component after receiving the data angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to show child component after receiving data from parent component.
I have make this steps to do it :

1. I've declare the component selector  in parent html page.
2. Send the data from parent to the child component `Show(text: string)` method:

   ```
   private text: string;
   Show (text: string){
       this.text = text;
   }
   ```
3. So after that i insert  `*ngIf="text"` for div in my child component to show data only when my component received it.

But when I call show method of my child component the `text` variable is empty and my child component doesn't shows. I think it is because child component selector in my parent html page create a new instance of object, that has an empty `text` value. How i can solve this ?

**UPDATED**

I am trying to use @Input. It's working. But working for string. How i can send to the input some class instance ?

Comment: Sending data from parent to child should be with @Input and not with a method

Comment: In template: `[text]="text` in child: `@Input text: string;`

Comment: You can add an boolean `isLoaded` to your component, initialy `false`, use *ngIf with this boolean, and set it to true just after you do `this.text = text`

Comment: A plunkr demonstrating the issue would be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example of parent HTML (only needed part):

```
<your-child-selector [text]="parentText"></your-child-selector>
```

`[text]-"parentText"` will pass `parentText` variable value from parent to child variable `text`.

In child component you should use `@Input` to receive data from parent like this:

```
@Input text: string;
```

And if you don't want to display anything in child component, while it didn't receive `text`, you can add `*ngIf` to hide (exclude) a part of DOM. Something like this (in child component):

This `*ngIf` will not show anything, while the child component will not receive `text` variable (using `@Input`) from parent component.

P.S: Don't forget to import `Input` in your child component!

Comment: Thank you ! But if i need to process the data before show. Can i do this with ngOnInit method? did the @Input data will received before ngonInit method ?

Comment: I'll test it in few minutes

Comment: Yes, it's pretty fast and data will be got before `OnInit`, you can start working with received value in `ngOnInit` already, and may be even earlier.

Comment: thank you. Can you check the update on the post, please ? There are some difficulties with it.

Comment: I have never tried to send the whole class, but if it's possible, I think you should use `@Input receivedClass: any;`. But I can suggest that no, it's impossible.